# What Swing Event is Fired when JFrame is Moved to Front of Desktop

Tags: java, events, swing

Say I have a window over top of my JFrame. I then click the JFrame's button in the TaskBar. The JFrame is now on top of the other window. What event would fire in this case?

I need to capture the event when my JFrame is brought in front of a another window to the top of the users desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WindowEvent.WINDOW_ACTIVATED](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html#WINDOW_ACTIVATED)